# Trying to normalize to BCNF

Tags: database-normalization

I am not sure if this is in BCNF or not, but the teacher told me that **INSTRUMENT** is in BCNF.. Is he messing with me? The teacher keeps messing up my mind on what is right and wrong and making me unsure. He keeps saying stuff that i've already thought of as clearly and I don't even get what he is saying.

**INSTRUMENT**(`InstrumentID,` InstrumentType, Tune, Performer, Adr, Phone, Availability) 
**NOTES**(`TitleNr,Tune,` Composer, Copies, Title, Performer)

So is this normalized? in BCNF:

**Instrument**(`InstrumentID`, InstrumentType, Tune, Availability, PerformerID*) 
**NOTES**(`TitleNr, Title,` Tune, Composer, Copies, PerformerID*) 
**PERFORMER**(`PerformerID`, Name, Adr, Phone)

Tune is in both INSTRUMENT and NOTES. Can it be in both?

Comment: Building (a little) on my answer below, what makes you think "Availability" has something to do with the instrument and not the performer? Or, for that matter, the tune, if "tune" means something like "orchestral score"?

Answer (score 1):

Each normal form requires the normal form preceding it.

1 NF - Your table only has atomic values i.e. no sets.

2 NF - Non-key attributes require every part of your key to be determined.

3 NF - Non-key attributes do not require anything but the key to be determined.

3.5 NF - If a non-key attribute can determine a key attribute, they must create a unique tuple.

My first concern is what TitleNr stands for.  If it is a unique ID then it isn't 2 NF, since the non-key attributes don't require Title to be determined.

My second concern is that InstrumentID is not a proper candidate key if Tune is included.  One instrument can play multiple Tunes, if Instrument.Tune represents what tunes have been played with that specific instrument.  It would be better to split those attributes out into another table, otherwise the other non-key attributes will make it not be 2 NF.

If it merely represents what Tunes are available, that can already be determined by the PerformerID, which isn't part of Instrument's key.  Then it is not 3 NF.

Comment: *"Each normal form requires the normal form preceding it."* Although that's generally true, it's *not* true of BCNF. Current definitions of BCNF don't say, for example, that a relation is in BCNF if and only if a) it's in 3NF, and b) (whatever)...  Instead, [BCNF is defined in terms of trivial dependencies and superkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form).

Answer (score 1):

Normalization applies to individual tables; it's based on functional dependencies.

Functional dependencies are determined by data, not by column names. Your instructor didn't give you any data. Trying to determine functional dependencies by column names alone is risky business, even when the columns are named well. Your columns aren't named well.

An imaginative database designer could probably come up with a predicate and sample data for the first "Instruments" table that demonstrates BCNF.

Maybe your instructor doesn't understand this stuff either. Wouldn't be the first.

Comment: 'Functional dependencies are determined by data'. I'd ague that's a bit backward. The functional dependencies typically represent business rules. Devising FDs based on the data in a table instance is as risky as guessing from the column names.

Comment: Business rules can't determine whether "Availability" has something to do the instrument or with the performer. And business rules quite often show a misunderstanding of the data. (Read the questions tagged "database-normalization" for many examples.) That's why functional dependencies depend on data, not on column names. More specifically, they depend on what the data *means*. Chris Date wrote a little about that in *An Introduction to Database Systems*.

Comment: Ahh, what the data _means_. That I'd agree with, and is what I implied with my reference "business rules" (and yes, they can be wrong, but I meant the _right_ business rules ;) My point was that any given dataset, assuming it is completely correct, can only help to exclude some candidate FDs and suggest some likely ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's in 2NF, not BCNF.

> INSTRUMENT(InstrumentID, InstrumentType, Tune, Performer, Adr, Phone,
>   Availability)

You really need to know the functional dependencies, but taking a guess I'd say the `adr` and `phone` are attributes of the performer, not the instrument. If attributes don't describe the key (in its entirety) then it's not BCNF.

Assume each performer has at most one phone number and address. If so, you would have the functional dependency:

```
Performer -> phone, adr
```

That is, there could be multiple instruments associated with the same performer, but in each case their phone and address would be the same (hence recorded redundantly).
I'll guess that the key for the Instrument relation is `InstrumentId`, so there's also a FD saying at most one performer is associated with each instrument;

```
InstrumentId -> Performer
```

That being the case, attributes `phone` and `adr` don't depend directly upon `InstrumentId`, but indirectly via `Performer`. Hence within this relation the FD `Performer -> phone, adr` is a *transitive dependency*. Any relation containing transitive dependencies by definition cannot be in anything higher than 2NF (second normal form). So it's not in 3NF, nor BCNF.

2NF doesn't allow *partial dependencies*. The good news is that since the key is only one attribute you don't have to worry about partial dependencies here: you can't have part of a single attribute.